# Easy question about orbital motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, orbital-motion, velocity

A satellite is orbiting the sun at the distance of $r$ and with velocity $v$ and on a circular orbit. (We name this orbit $O_1$). We want to change its orbit. The new orbit $O_2$ is perpendicular to $O_1$ with the same distance from the sun and hence the same velocity. How much we should change its velocity and energy? ($v<<c$ so it is classical)

Somewhere answered this question that we must first zero the horizontal velocity and then give it vertical velocity so $2v$ is the change in velocity. and $\Delta E = 0.5 m v^2  + 0.5 m v^2 = m v^2$. The first for zeroing the horizontal and the second for giving vertical velocity.

Somewhere else said the "Velocity-Change" vector is $\sqrt{v^2 + v^2} = \sqrt{2} v$ and hence $\Delta E \ = 0.5 m (\sqrt{2}v)^2 =  m  v^2$.

The energy change of both is the same but I think their way to get this is different. I want to know which one is physically correct? (or maybe both is the same thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get those two responses? I expect this was not a stackexchange network site. I'll restrain myself from derogating other sites. If this was an SE site, let us know.

The first response is complete nonsense. The person who wrote that response doesn't know about vectors or orbital mechanics. The "somewhere else" response is correct.